# How to extract sibling text from XML using XPath?

Tags: xml, xpath, powershell

I have this simple XML document. I want to extact the pairs of `("foo","bar")` and `("baz","zab")` using, if at all possible, just `select-xml`. Is it possile and how?

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<tag>
  <outer>
    <a>foo</a>
    <b>bar</b>
  </outer>
  <outer>
    <a>baz</a>
    <b>zab</b>
  </outer>
</tag>
```

The problem I am having is that successive invocations of `select-xml` lose the context of the previous invocation of `select-xml` and AFAIK the order of nodes returned by it is undefined, so just zipping two lists seems unusable. Or am I wrong that the order of the nodes returned by it is the order in the document?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can read the file :

```
$xml = [xml](Get-Content .\test.xml)
```

And then use :

```
$xml.tag.outer
```

Or Like this :

```
foreach ($outer in $xml.tag.outer)
{
  $outer.a
  $outer.b
}
```

With `Select-Xml` :

```
Clear-Host

$InputText = @"

<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>   
<tag>   
  <outer>   
    <a>foo</a>   
    <b>bar</b>   
  </outer>   
  <outer>   
    <a>baz</a>   
    <b>zab</b>   
  </outer>   
</tag>
"@ 

$xml = [xml]($InputText)

$nodes = Select-Xml -Xml $xml -XPath "//outer"

foreach ($node in $nodes)
{
 $node.node.a
}
```

Comment: @JPBland: It works, awesome! I did not know I could access the nodes in DOM like manner.